# Singular verb for plural subject

Tags: grammatical-number

I’ve found some examples like:

> Alles **ist** richtig.
>
> Meine Familie **ist** sehr geil.

Are there other examples of same usage?

Comment: "Familie" is a singular subject, not plural, no? Same for "Alles".

Comment: "Famillie" is singular? I didn't know that. "Famillie" refers to more than one person, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Explorer eine Familie, zwei Familien (like in all other languages I know: one family, two families)

Comment: @splattne: But in my language, we use plural verb for "Family".

Comment: "Meine Familie ist sehr geil." - this is kind of a strange example sentence, would you mind changing it to "Meine Familie ist sehr nett."? ^^

Comment: To explain ladybug's comment: *Geil* can mean either "very good" in youthful, colloquial speech, or it can mean "horny", which was probably not what you're trying to say.

Comment: With a sentence as "Meine  Familie is sehr geil" I would be very, very careful. "geil" is youngster slang for good, but the normal meaning  refers to sex and you could get very curious reactions if you use such a sentence in normal situations. As a learner I would avoid such language.

Comment: @user128 So your language is inconsistent in noun-verb agreement, not German.

Answer (score 11):

*Familie* and *alles* are **not plural words**. They define single entities. So, using the singular conjugated verb is perfectly right in these cases.

Comment: "plural words"? When I say alles, the auditor expect a plural verb like "sind".Am I right, or it's my illusion?

Comment: @Explorer *Alle sind* but *alles ist*. Those are not the same words.

Comment: It's your illusion. Or your pre-conception that is based on the structure of your native language. "Alles ist gut". "Alle sind im Bett". These are different constructs. "Alles" is a singular subject. "Alle" is a plural subject. The differences may be subtle and hard to understand, but they _DO_ exist.

Comment: Oh, and by the way: Who is "the auditor"?

Comment: @Deceze: But "alles" refers to more than one thing. I know these are grammatically **singular**.

Comment: @Explorer And you're talking about grammar issues here, so the grammatical singularity counts, not the meaning. :)

Comment: @deceze: "We"? We're talking about German, not grammar.

Comment: @Explorer Though Grammar is an inevitable aspect of a language.

Comment: @user128: Not being a native English speaker and not being an expert for the English language: I think it's like "Everything" in English. "Everything" also generally does mean multiple objects, but you are saying e.g. "Everything is good" or "Everything was easily accessible" instead of "Everything are good" or "Everything were easily accessible".

Answer (score 10):

I see this is going to be too long for a comment.

Having a single word describe more than one thing does not mean the word is plural. Most of the time plurality conforms to what the word describes in its most direct sense.

> Alle *sind* im Bett.

Here we have multiple people being described.

> Alles *ist* gut.

Here it refers to a situation or just … *everything*; not two or five things in particular.

> Adam und Eva *gehen* durch den Garten.

Here the subject consists of two persons so we use plural.

> Eine Herde Schafe *ist* auf der Wiese.

Now it gets more subtle. Although a herd of sheep consists of multiple sheep, we describe the herd as a whole. We don’t mean a small subset of sheep but address all of them at the same time. I don’t know if this makes sense (in particular the difference between this and the first example).

It’s more or less the same with *Familie*. That word is used to address a group of people that belongs together in a very rigid fashion.

Answer (score 9):

The confusion about this for English speakers comes from a difference between English and German grammatical logic.

In German verbs conjugate for the grammatical number of the noun, even if that singular noun represents a group of people or things.

In English it's common to conjugate according to the extrapolated number the noun represents. It's probably incorrect on some level but extremely prevalent.

So in English you might say *the family are* because "the family" is more than one person, but in German you say *die Familie ist* because you are talking about one family.

In this article from [The Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/sport/2011/may/24/stuart-law-sri-lanka-england), they use *England are* even though there isn't more than one England, because they are talking about the English team of players. You don't do this in German.

Comment: I don't think _the family are_ is correct but now you made me unsure. Googlefight favors _is_.

Comment: There are certainly situations where you would say is. It possibly depends on whether "the family" is being used to refer to specific people or not - on googlefight "your family are" beats "your family is". I'm talking from a UK English perspective - it may differ elsewhere.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Good to know!

Comment: **Usage is different between UK and US English.** In the UK, they tend to say _the family are_ or _England are_ because it's a group of people. In the US, we tend to say _the family is_ or _America is_ because the nouns are grammatically singular. It sounds like **German is more like American English in this regard.**