# Steht die Tätigkeit einer Musikgruppe im Plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Vor kurzem bin ich mal wieder über diese Frage gestolpert, als ich auf einer CD von Scala las:

> Scala chante les plus belles chansons de [...]

Scala ist ein belgischer Mädchenchor; ohne Frage also eine größere Anzahl von Personen. Trotzdem steht das Verb nicht nur in diesem französischen Untertitel im Singular, sondern auch in den deutschen Texten:

> Scala tritt [...] auf.

Dies scheint mir einigermaßen logisch, entsprechend [Singular verb for plural subject](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/400/singular-verb-for-plural-subject) ist das ja eine Entität und somit steht das Verb im Singular. Aber sehr häufig findet man Beschreibungen, in denen der Plural verwendet wird:

> Juli traten auch dieses Jahr zur Kieler Woche bei Regen auf.

(das klingt übrigens wie ein Scherz, seltsamerweise regnet es aber tatsächlich immer, wenn diese Band zur Kieler Woche auftritt...)

Diese Form sieht man häufiger bei Musikgruppen, natürlich nie bei Einzelpersonen. Die Häufigkeit des Auftreten lässt in mir aber die Frage aufkommen, ob es nicht doch korrekt sein könnte.

Gibt es hier eine eindeutige Regel?

Comment: Der Chor schreit, der Kongress tanzt, das Quartett rockt, die Beatles grooven, die Stones säuseln, die Band schweigt. Bei den Beatles ist der Eigenname ein Plural, wie bei den Stones. Aber Deep Purple orgelt sich was zurecht, singt von den `Mothers of Invetion`, welche ins erste Hotel am Platz gezogen waren, weil die Mamas wieder Mz. sind. Was fehlt ist ein Einzelgenie, dass im Künstlernamen als Mehrzahl daherkommt - gibt es vielleicht schon, oder spätestens morgen. :)

Comment: Tu dir keinen Zwang an, das als Antwort zu posten.

Comment: Na ich weiß nicht - es ist ja nur ein Haufen Beispiele, aber nichts substantiell Neues.

Answer (score 6):

Ich würde es davon abhängig machen, in welcher grammatischen Funktion ein Begriff benutzt wird:

- "Die Beatles" - pluralischer Eigenname, Verb steht kongruierend im Plural;
- "Der Beatle" - neu gebildeter Gattungsbegriff, Verb im Singular;
- "Juli (Band)" - Eigenname ohne konkreten Numerus, sprachlich aber wohl häufig verkürzt für "... die Band Juli ..." - das Nomen, zu dem das Verb kongruiert, wäre hier "die Band", nicht "Juli", daher Singular.

Das sind die wohl unstrittigen Fälle. Im Beispiel "Der Beatle" könnte der **Gattungsbegriff** aber auch im Plural verwendet werden (Nach dem Attentat auf John Lennon: "die drei übrigen Beatles"). Dem Nomen "Die Beatles" sieht man also nicht an, ob es eine Eindeutschung des pluralischen Bandnamens darstellt oder den Plural der "Gattungsbezeichnung" "Beatle". Damit ist auch nicht eindeutig, ob die Band insgesamt gemeint ist oder eine Untermenge ihrer Mitglieder.

Jetzt die Frage: Kann "Juli" auch zu einer Art Gattungsbezeichnung für das Bandmitglied werden? Also "der Juli" bzw. "die Juli"? Oder geht das nur für pluralische Namen, oder auch dort nur bei Phantasienamen? Bei "Stones" wohl noch möglich, aber bei "Doors" droht unfreiwillige Komik...

Vielleicht besser: Die Formulierung "Juli spielen übermorgen im..." wird als grammatikalisch unvollständig angesehen, aber als elliptische Formulierung akzeptiert: "[Die Mitglieder der Band] Juli spielen übermorgen in..." - das erfordert die wenigsten Verrenkungen, riecht aber nach Notlösung für Fälle, bei denen der Gruppenname nicht explizit im Plural steht.

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe das gerade mal an einer meiner Lieblingsbands ausprobiert und festgestellt, dass beides geht:

> Tiamat spielt demnächst wieder in München.
>
> Tiamat spielen demnächst wieder in München.

Beides klingt für mich gleichwertig, einmal hat man eben die Band/Musikgruppe im Kopf, einmal die einzelnen Personen/Musiker.

Ausnahmen sind normalerweise Bands/Gruppen, die einen Artikel im Namen tragen:

> Die Ärzte geben ein Geheimkonzert.

niemals: »Die Ärzte gibt ein Geheimkonzert«,  nur »Die Band ›Die Ärzte‹ gibt …«, das wäre aber sehr unüblich.

> Die Bloodhound Gang spielt im Oktober in Berlin.

»Die Bloodhound Gang spielen« ginge nicht, aber sehr wohl: »Hey, kennst du die Bloodhound Gang? Die spielen im Oktober in Berlin.«