# Plural nouns with singular use

Tags: noun, grammatical-number

In English there are some nouns that have plural form but are used with a singular verb:

> economics, statistics, measles, maths etc.

Are there nouns like these in German?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/400/singular-verb-for-plural-subject

Comment: Reading the question, the first two things that came to my mind were *Masern* and *Windpocken*, but they are used like plural-only as in *Ich habe die Masern*. I'm actually not sure whether there is a single *Maser* or *Windpocke*.

Comment: *Weihnachten* for sure, and probably *Ostern* and *Pfingsten* as well.

Comment: @Uwe Bist du sicher, dass es sich dabei um Pluralformen handelt? (Bei *Weihnachten* kann ich deine Einordnung zwar noch nachvollziehen, *das Weihnachten dieses Jahres* ist aber eine andere Form als *die Weihnachten der letzten fünf Jahre.)*

Comment: @Jan Ja, bin ich. Ich hab's gerade nochmal im Grimm nachgeschaut.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question was to find only plural forms that are used with singular verbs. E.g. *Masern* is always used with plural verbs as in *In unserer Schule **sind** die Masern ausgebrochen.* *Weihnachten* and *Ostern* are correct examples: *Ostern **hat** uns in diesem Jahr viel Freude bereitet.* *Weihnachten **ist** ein Fest für die ganze Familie*. Here, *Ostern* and *Weihnachten* are used in the sense of *Das Osterfest* and *Das Weihnachtsfest* which are singular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

According to Grimm's Wörterbuch, the singular forms
[*Weihnachten*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW13964#XGW13964) and [*Pfingsten*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GP03626#XGP03626) go back to old dative plural forms (Middle High German: *(ze den) wîhen nahten*, *(ze den) pfingsten*).
[*Ostern*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GO02466#XGO02466) also used to be a plural form (Singular: *Oster*) that developed into a new singular.

Comment: I don’t think those two represent what OP is looking for well, because while both words *derived* from plural forms, they are nowadays considered *singular* forms of neuter genus. *Measles,* however, is clearly still the plural of *measle* even though it conjugates verbs as if it were singular.

Comment: Auch bei *Weihnachten*, *Ostern* und *Pfingsten* hat sich noch ein Rest
ihrer Vorgeschichte als Plurale erhalten. Man merkt es zum Beispiel
daran, daß alle Ableitungsformen durchgehend von den alten Singularen
abgeleitet sind (*Osterfeuer*, *Weihnachtsfeier*). Noch deutlicher ist
es aber bei den Grußformeln: Bei *Frohes neues Jahr!* oder *Schönes Wochenende!* kann man optional
den Singularartikel *ein* vorstellen. Bei *Weihnachten*, *Ostern* und
*Pfingsten* geht das nicht; *Eine frohe Ostern!* wäre völlig unidiomatisch.

Comment: ... ausserdem sind zwei frohe Ostern sowieso besser.

Comment: "Eine frohe Ostern wünsche ich dir" finde ich jetzt nicht schlecht.

Comment: @jona *"Ostern"* als Femininum? Wo ist denn das üblich? Standardsprachlich
ist *Ostern* ein Neutrum, aber dann kann *"Frohe Ostern!"* eben
nur ein Plural sein. Wenn man den Singular verwenden will, dann wäre das *"Frohes Ostern!"*; da
könnte man tatsächlich den unbestimmten Artikel vorsetzen,
also *"Ein frohes Ostern!"*

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%22eine+frohe+ostern%22 :)